# How can I fix document lookup for Android Studio while I'm using flutter framework?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I want to know how I could fix this issue:
[problem-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQpOL.png)
as you can see there is no hint about how I can Implement and what I should do for these properties.

I have tried many paradigms, such as code completion and installing flutter packages for Android Studio, but I didn't get my desired result.

Comment: Did you add flutter extension?